# Android Studio upgrade wants to delete "Unexpected" .jks files?

Tags: android-studio, keystore

I just opened Android Studio for the first time in a few months, and accepted the option of updating it. The update process has stopped with the message that some conflicts were found in the installation area. My two .jks files were flagged as "unexpected files", and the only solution being offered is to delete them.
Presumably if I allow them to be deleted I'll lose my keystores. Since I don't know how or if I can restore them from a backup copy, how should I proceed?

Comment: So copy the file somewhere else first?

Comment: Yes but (a) what's the process for restoring them and (b) why is Android Studio rejecting them in the first place?

Comment: And a further complication - it says that the files it is objecting to are in /jre/bin, but I can only find ONE of the two files that it's referring to in my /jre/bin folder.